# mysqld stopped working..can't restart...need help?

Tags: mysql

i was just checking somethings and noticed mysqld is not running in  parallels power panel control panel...but my websites on the server were all working fine, which use mysql databases...so really strange

So i tried to restart mysqld but got errors and can't restart and now all my websites are all offline now saying error connecting to database.

logged in as root and tried

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

and got this error

```
ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file
```

What do i do next?

What do i do? Please help!

Comment: look at MySQL log, normally in `/var/log/mysql.log` or `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

Comment: and do what next? what do i do when i look at it? please explain

Comment: at the end of that file, there might be an error. copy it here and you can get better help.

Comment: how do i see the file again because not working `vi /var/log/mysql.log ` but don't see anything....also can i use nano editor" tried `nano /var/log/mysql.log ` but got `-bash: nano: command not found`

Comment: u still there ?

Comment: try with `less` or `tail -n 40 mysql.log`, and study the basics of Linux command line after this is solved. but first check if it's in there... with `ls` it could be in a different location. try `locate mysql.log` -- on Ubuntu I've `/var/log/mysql.log` empty, and `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` is the real one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your hard drive out of space? Run:

```
df -h
```

Or try renaming /etc/my.cnf to /etc/my.cnf.old and it'll rebuild a new my.cnf.

It may also be in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf directory

UPDATE:

After chatting, we figured out that mysql was still running. Apparently, some people have reported this error message is caused when mysql doesn't shut down properly, but thinks it's shut down.

So we ran

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

To see running processes, then,

```
kill 23445 34255
```

To stop the processes...

Then /etc/init.d/mysqld start

to start the server back up.

Comment: no hard drive has 94GB free

Comment: What about renaming the my.cnf file?

Comment: how do i rename the my.cnf file and where do i see the my.cnf file?

Comment: ls -lah /etc/my.cnf   OR    ls -lah /etc/mysql   THEN    mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.old

Comment: i mean i am not trying do anything that will cause arm or i cannot reverse...so if i rename that file...will i be able to reverse that? and what will that do really?

Comment: You always want to be able to reverse a change. Hence the renaming

Comment: tried both `ls -lah /etc/my.cnf` OR `ls -lah /etc/mysql` and got this error `ls: /etc/mysql: No such file or directory`

Comment: what was the output for ls -lah /etc/my.cnf ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4947/discussion-between-homer6-and-grant-tailor)

Comment: +1 for chat assistance with OP